# Any update to Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OWIN 5.2.3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have an app using Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OWIN. Installed the latest version (5.2.3) on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/) and realized it hasn't been updated since February 9, 2015.

There have been individual updates the following packages since 5.2.3 was released:

- Newtonsoft.Json
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener

Is there a plan for updating or maintaining Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OWIN moving forward?

Is it safe to update the packages above?

FYI. I'm running .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated all of those packages to the latest versions and have not seen any ill effects in any of my applications.  It's not really unusual for a package to not receive updates if it is considered stable and there are no new relevant features to release.  I would expect that to change when ASP.NET Core is officially released.